# knife intersect cut with python scripting?

Tags: python

I want to cut some holes in a shape with a python script in Blender (3.3)
I have some images here illustrating a simplified version of what I want to do, to remove the cylinder shape from the cube, but without leaving "walls" of geometry where the cylinder cuts through the cube. I just want two holes on either side of the cube.

So starting with this:

[image]

and ending something like this:

[image]

not this, which is the result of a boolean intersect.

[image]

I need to do this all with python scripting, I am experienced with python scripting but new to blender, and honestly am finding the api and workflow very confusing.

Comment: I don't know python but suspect that you want to use the normal Blender Knife Project equivalent which seems to be [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.knife_project) in the Blender python docs.

Answer (score 0):

I used a circle mesh instead of a cylinder

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(radius=0.5, location=(0, 0, 2))

cube = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
circle = bpy.data.objects["Circle"]
 
ctx = bpy.context
 
old_type = ctx.area.type    
ctx.area.type = 'VIEW_3D'

bpy.ops.view3d.view_axis(type='TOP')

# the view 3d area needs to be updated or else the view won't stay in top view. If you plan on running the script multiple times and all future runs will stay in top view, you can omit this line for future runs.
ctx.area.spaces.active.region_3d.update()

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
ctx.view_layer.objects.active = cube
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = "EDIT")
circle.select_set(True)

win      = ctx.window
scr      = win.screen
areas3d  = [area for area in scr.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D']
region   = [region for region in areas3d[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW']

override = {'area':areas3d[0], 'region':region[0]}

bpy.ops.mesh.knife_project(override, cut_through=True)

bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='FACE')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = "OBJECT")
ctx.area.type = old_type
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to work? I just get a cube and an outline of a circle floating above it?

Comment: Also didn't work for me

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie  I think it should work now after adding the "region_3d.update()" line. Try it out!